# How to execute a method from a subclass inside a "for" whose variable is the superclass?

Tags: java, oop, methods

I have a class named Agent:

```
abstract public class Agent {
// this class doesn't has the method "method_A"
}
```

And a class AgentHistoric:

```
public class AgentHistoric extends Agent{
    public void method_A(){
    code
    }
}
```

I have also classes RandomAgent, AgentAlways0, etc, all extending the abstract class Agent, but only AgentHistoric has the method "method_A".

Suppose I created AgentHistoric's objetcs,  RandomAgent's objetcs, etc, and I have added them to an ArrayList named agents.

In another class, I have the following code:

```
for (Agent ag: this.agents ){
    ag.update(); // all Agent's subclasses have this method
   if (ag.returntype() == AgentHistoric){ // I know there's a more elegant way, but OK
       method_A() } // error!
}
```

How can I execute a exclusive method of AgentHistoric in this loop?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `instanceof` operator to determine if `ag` is an `AgentHistoric`.  If so, cast `ag` to an `AgentHistoric`, then call `method_A`.

Comment: May you explain me, please, what do you mean by "cast ag to an AgentHistoric, then call method_A"? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: I mean `AgentHistoric agh = (AgentHistoric) ag;` and `agh.method_A();`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to use `instanceof` operator?

```
if (ag instanceof AgentHistoric){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `instanceof`, a more "OO way" of doing it is just NOT override `method_A` in the classes that you want to run `Agent.method_A()` or if you want to do additional work, call `super.method_A()` while in the classes that you want to change the implementation - override the method.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler only knows that the variable `ag` is of type `Agent` which, as you said yourself, has no `method_A` defined. In order to call `method_A`, you need to cast `ag` to an instance of `AgentHistoric`.

As others have said, you can use the `instanceof` operator to check that the current assignment of `ag` is in fact an `AgentHistoric` instance.